# accessing service locator in view helper

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers, service-locator

I cannot access the service locator in my custom view helper. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    namespace Sam\View\Helper;

    use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;

    class Authenticated extends AbstractHelper imeplements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
    {
        protected $authservice;

        public function __invoke()
        {
           if (!$this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()){
                return false;
            }
            return true;        
        }

        public function getAuthService()
        {
            if (! $this->authservice) {
                $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
            }
            return $this->authservice;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the full code for the helper? It looks like you're missing a `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait` line in the class.

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, if you want to use the service locator trait, you need a `use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait` line in the class. What you currently have should give you an error because the methods defined by the `ServiceLocatorAware` interface you're implementing are missing.